# Fade out one image and fade in another with css animations

Tags: css-animations

I have two images I'd like to alternate between. I'd like to have one image fade out completely, then have the second image fade in. I'd like the two images to cycle like the infinitely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask good questions and receive helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily achieve this, by using `keyframes` for your `opacity` and by giving your second image an `animation-delay` of half the time your animation takes.

```css
.fadein {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
.fadein img {
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

#f2 {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadein">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" id="f1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/abc/fff" id="f2">
</div>
```